# Operator + with linked list ADT

Tags: c++

I have a project which you import a polynomial (Coefficient and exponent) into a linked list with s structure of Coefficient, Exponent, and a pointer to the next node. I have the storage all set but am having problems with the operators. I have got the = all set but going beyond that im having problems.

So far I have

```
Poly Poly::operator+ (const Poly& orig){
    bool firstTime = 0;
    Poly temp;
    temp.Head = new PolyTerm;
    temp.Size = 1;
    ptrType New = temp.Head;
    ptrType cur = Head;
    for(int i = 1; i <= Size; i++) {
            ptrType org = orig.Head;
            for(int j = 1; i <= orig.ListLength(); j++) {
                    if(org->exp == cur->exp) {
                            if(firstTime) {
                                    New->Next = new PolyTerm;
                                    New = New->Next;
                                    New->Next = NULL;
                                    temp.Size += 1;
                            }
                            New->coef = ((cur->coef) + (org->coef));
                            New->exp = cur->exp;
                            firstTime = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    org = org->Next;

            }
            cur = cur->Next;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

it seems to run fine and with break points it gets to return and returns, but my program hangs after that. Im not sure what I have done wrong but i think it is simple

I hope I have provided enough info. Feel free to ask something

Comment: `firstTime` is initially `false`. You will not enter `if()` condition firstTime. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes thats what I want, It should only happen after the first time

Comment: @BrianMcNamara: Maybe that should be called "notFirstTime" then? (And initialized to `false`)

Comment: @BrianMcNamara: It's more readable to call it `firstTime` initialize it to `true`, and test `if (!firstTime)`.

Comment: Please provide a complete code sample and a detailed description of the failure you are experiencing. How are the classes Poly, PolyTerm, ptrType defined? What operations are you performing on these objects? Is the operator= definition relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you defined the Poly type.
This is what I'd do: The poly type stores the value of a polynomial, like int stores a number. (You might want to implement operator==, too.)

```
#include <memory>

template<typename COEF,typename EXP>
struct PolyList {
    COEF coef;
    EXP  exp;
    std::shared_ptr<const PolyList<COEF,EXP>> next;
    template<typename C,typename E>
    PolyList(C coef,E exp):coef(coef),exp(exp){}
};

template<typename COEF,typename EXP>
struct poly : public std::shared_ptr<const PolyList<COEF,EXP>> {
    template<typename X>
    poly(X x):std::shared_ptr<const PolyList<COEF,EXP>>(x){}
    poly(){}
};

template<typename COEF,typename EXP>
poly<COEF,EXP> operator+(poly<COEF,EXP> a,poly<COEF,EXP> b)
{
    if(!a) return b;
    if(!b) return a;
    if(a->exp > b->exp){
        PolyList<COEF,EXP> *ret = new PolyList<COEF,EXP>(a->coef,a->exp);
        ret->next = a->next + b;
        return ret;
    }
    if(a->exp < b->exp) return b+a;
    // a->exp == b->exp
    COEF c = a->coef + b->coef;
    if(!c) return a->next + b->next;
    // c!=0
    PolyList<COEF,EXP> *ret = new PolyList<COEF,EXP>(c,a->exp);
    ret->next = a->next + b->next;
    return ret;
}
```